# Create Slick carousel after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create one slick carousel after the page load. The slick is this one: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

If I put the code in the html, it loads correctly when page loads, but when I append some more slideshow code with JS and run the:

```
$('.slideshow').slick({
    dots:false,
    arrows:false,
    pauseOnHover:false,
    autoplay:true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 500,
    fade: false,
    cssEase: 'linear',
    vertical: false,
    verticalSwiping: false
});
```

Te slideshow turns like that:

```
<div class="slideshow slick-initialized slick-slider" id="PREVcarr1" name="PREVcarr1">
    <div aria-live="polite" class="slick-list draggable">
        <div class="slick-track" style="opacity: 1; width: 0px; left: 0px;" role="listbox">
        </div>
    </div>
    <img src="#">
    <img src="#">
    <img src="#">
    ...
</div>
```

I think the images are not loading inside the correct div.

The .append looks like that:

```
$('#preview').append("<div class='slideshow' id='PREVcarr"+carrnum+"' name='PREVcarr"+carrnum+"'><img...><img...></div>");
```

Comment: You need to call $('.slideshow').slick() function after append.

Comment: I do it, but the same result. The slideshow seems to load but the images are out of it. @AbdullahAMalik

Comment: Then you need to edit your question and show your html that how does it look like before you append it.

Comment: You need to call "slickAdd" function instead of append.